# scala colon right arrow key vs only colon

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

In Play scala html template, one can specify

> @(title: String)(content: Html)

or

> @(title: String)(content: => Html)

What is the difference?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Writing `parameter: => Html` is called a 'by name parameter'.

Example:

```
def x = {
  println("executing x")
  1 + 2
}

def y(x:Int) = {
  println("in method y")
  println("value of x: " + x)
}

def z(x: => Int) = {
  println("in method z")
  println("value of x: " + x)
}

y(x)
//results in:
//executing x
//in method y
//value of x: 3

z(x)
//results in:
//in method z
//executing x
//value of x: 3
```

By name parameters are executed when used. The problem with this is that they can be evaluated more than once.

A good example would be an if statement. Let's say if was a method like this:

```
def if(condition:Boolean, then: => String, else: => String)
```

It would be a waste to evaluate both `then` and `else` before the method is executed. We know only one of the expressions will be executed, the condition is either `true` or `false`. That's the reason `when` and `else` are defined as 'by name' parameters.

This concept is explained in the Scala course: https://www.coursera.org/course/progfun